# CoreML: Can I use two machine learning models (mlmodel files) in one project?

Tags: swift, ios11, xcode9-beta, coreml

I've created a small sample program to test CoreML. Basic idea is to combine the results of several models for example VGG16 and Resnet50.

When I try to compile my project I'm getting this error:

[image]

Is it possible to use two or more model files in one project? If I remove one of the mlmodel files it compiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I had that issue. You need to go to build settings, and in the CoreML section change the language from 'Automatic' to 'Swift'